# Replace dt element with jQuery (phpBB)

Tags: jquery, phpbb

I tried searching, but all the examples and answers I found I couldn't get to work.

phpBB has the following lines of code:

```
    <!-- IF topicrow.S_FIRST_ROW or not topicrow.S_TOPIC_TYPE_SWITCH -->
    <div class="forumbg<!-- IF topicrow.S_TOPIC_TYPE_SWITCH and (topicrow.S_POST_ANNOUNCE or topicrow.S_POST_GLOBAL) --> announcement<!-- ENDIF -->">
    <div class="inner">
    <ul class="topiclist">
        <li class="header">
            <dl class="row-item">
                <dt<!-- IF S_DISPLAY_ACTIVE --> id="active_topics"<!-- ENDIF -->><div class="list-inner"><!-- IF S_DISPLAY_ACTIVE -->{L_ACTIVE_TOPICS}<!-- ELSEIF topicrow.S_TOPIC_TYPE_SWITCH and (topicrow.S_POST_ANNOUNCE or topicrow.S_POST_GLOBAL) -->{L_ANNOUNCEMENTS}<!-- ELSE -->{L_TOPICS}<!-- ENDIF --></div></dt>
                <dd class="posts">{L_REPLIES}</dd>
                <dd class="views">{L_VIEWS}</dd>
                <dd class="lastpost"><span>{L_LAST_POST}</span></dd>
            </dl>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

I'm trying to relace this part (the entire line)

```
<dt<!-- IF S_DISPLAY_ACTIVE --> id="active_topics"<!-- ENDIF -->>
    <div class="list-inner">
        <!-- IF S_DISPLAY_ACTIVE -->{L_ACTIVE_TOPICS}
        <!-- ELSEIF topicrow.S_TOPIC_TYPE_SWITCH and (topicrow.S_POST_ANNOUNCE or topicrow.S_POST_GLOBAL) -->{L_ANNOUNCEMENTS}
        <!-- ELSE -->{L_TOPICS}<!-- ENDIF -->
    </div>
</dt>
```

For reference, I need to change it to

```
<dt<!-- IF S_DISPLAY_ACTIVE --> id="active_topics"<!-- ENDIF -->>
    <div class="list-inner">
        <!-- IF S_DISPLAY_ACTIVE -->{L_ACTIVE_TOPICS}
        <!-- ELSEIF topicrow.S_TOPIC_TYPE eq 3 -->{L_GLOBAL_ANNOUNCEMENTS}
        <!-- ELSEIF (topicrow.S_POST_ANNOUNCE or topicrow.S_POST_GLOBAL) eq 2 -->{L_ANNOUNCEMENTS}
        <!-- ELSEIF topicrow.S_TOPIC_TYPE eq 1 -->{L_STICKY}
        <!-- ELSE -->{L_TOPICS}<!-- ENDIF -->
    </div>
</dt>
```

Can someone provide the entire jquery code I need to make this work please? Thank you.

Comment: This structure is a template. You should look at the output (view-source in your browser).

Comment: `$('#active_topics').replaceWith(....................)`

Comment: Also, If you want to change logic of displaying, in this case, i am not sure that jQuery is right tool. Modify template, rather...

Comment: phpBB forbides modifying the template in extensions (since 3.1.x). As for the "active_topics' id suggestion, I need this to modify the dt element without affecting the 'active_topics' id.

Comment: Could you be more precise ? Please provide us the template name and the php page you want to alter.

Comment: Provide example HTML output, pre-rendered template isn't helpful.

Answer (score 1):

phpBB only forbides modifying core php files. If you want to modify data, you have to use extension. But you aren't in this case.

For template, it is recommanded to use Event Template extension especially when you have to add some new features. But you can *alter* your template, especially on your case !

Here is the good practice :

Create a new style heriting prosilver

```
# General Information about youstyle
name = mystyle
copyright = © phpBB Limited, 2016
style_version = 3.1.10
phpbb_version = 3.1.10

# Defining a different template bitfield
# template_bitfield = lNg=

# Parent style
# Set value to empty or to this style's name
# if this style does not have a parent style
parent = prosilver
```

Copy/paste the template file [viewforum.phtml](https://github.com/phpbb/phpbb/blob/master/phpBB/styles/prosilver/template/viewforum_body.html), you wanna alter in your new style directories and alter it directly.

```
phpBB/styles/mystyle/template/viewforum_body.html
```

Use your admin panel to test your modification. When it is done, change the default template from `prosilver` to `mystyle`

Here is a good documentation about [template Inheritance](https://wiki.phpbb.com/Template_Inheritance_Changes_in_3.1)